# Numbers and Lines

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

You stumble upon this puzzle in the newspaper, composed of only lines and numbers.

13—17

13—84

13—113

17—117

34—53

53—115

82—84

113—17

117—113

Unfortunately, you're a bit stuck. You call upon your friend Sherlock for a hint (he's very good at puzzles). After looking at it for a minute, he finally replies. "Elementary, my dear friend. I'm sure you can connect the dots yourself. Once you're done, the answer is another puzzle."

Well, that wasn't very helpful. Or was it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is indeed...

> Elementary:
>
>  [image]
>
> As the instructions tell us to draw lines on the periodic table between the elements, given by their atomic numbers.

This gives us...

> this peculiar shape:
>
>  [image: m]

This is

> [*The original* tangram puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangram)! In Tangrams, you take the pieces and rearrange them to get another picture. This particular tangram is famous and has a few 'solutions':
>
>  [image]

---

Comment: Just pipped me to the post! Classic Christmas cracker shape recognition :) +1

Comment: @Stiv Ironically I actually didn't recognise the picture at all :P

Comment: You are correct! Nice work :)